# login form is not working. I am not able to login as a customer

Tags: python, django

The login form is not working. My signup form is working but LoginForm isn't.
Whenever I login to the customer that error message is showing which is defined in an `error_msg` for debugging.

forms.py

```
class LoginForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('email','password')

        widgets = {
            'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-sm'}),
            'password': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-sm'})
        }
```

views.py

```
def login(request):
    form = LoginForm
    error_msg = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(request, email = email, password = password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('services')
        else:
            error_msg = "Email or Password Wrong!!"
    return render(request, 'core/login.html', {'form': form, 'error_msg': error_msg})
```

Login.html

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}

                {{ form.as_p }}

                <!-- Button -->
                <div class="form-group text-center mt-3">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"> Login </button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    GenderChoice = (
        ("M","Male"),
        ("F","Female")
        )

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length = 1, choices=GenderChoice, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=8, null=True)
```

can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: `Customer` is not being used as `User` model. Please check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/) on how to use Django's authenitcation.

Comment: so now how can I add customers to the User model? or link customers to User Model. I don't know what to do I never use it before. plz help me.

Comment: you may look this article it can help you to find the best solution for your case - https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `AbstractUser` to add customers to the User model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    GenderChoice = (
        ("M","Male"),
        ("F","Female")
        )
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length = 1, choices=GenderChoice, null=True)
```

`first_name` and `last_name` are default fields, you can refer to here：[enter link description here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/)